# Prove that $(a \cdot b) \text{ mod } n = ((a \text{ mod } n) \cdot (b \text{ mod } n)) \text{ mod } n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Prove for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, n >1$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ that
>   $$(a \cdot b) \text{ mod } n = ((a \text{ mod } n) \cdot (b \text{ mod
> } n)) \text{ mod } n$$

I'm not sure if this is a proof but I tried another way this time:

Let $x=a \text{ mod } n$, let $y= b \text{ mod } n$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\Rightarrow$

$(x \cdot y) \text{ mod } n= (a \cdot b) \text{ mod } n$

Create a "matching" $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$a=x+pn$ and $b=y+qn$

$\Rightarrow ((x+pn)(y+qn)) \text{ mod } n= (xy+xqn+ypn+pqn^{2}) \text{ mod } n=(xy+n(xq+yp+pqn)) \text{ mod } n = (x \cdot y) \text{ mod } n$

---

I hope this is correct and counts as proof?

Comment: Note that in mathematics it is uncommon to use $\text{mod}$ as an operator. Rather, one would write $a \equiv b \ (\text{mod } n)$ as an abbreviation for $n \mid a - b$. Still, if you really want to, you can define $\text{mod}$ as an operator, but what *exactly* is the definition? You will at some point need to use it.

Comment: $a\equiv b \pmod m$ is defined to be equivalent to $\frac{a-b}{m}\in\mathbb{Z}$, at least that's how Gauss(the inventor of this notation) did it.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Apparently some teachers (even university ones, I've seen them myself...) use $a\mod n$ to denote the remainder of $a$ when dividing by $n$. FYI (as far as I understand) the point in this is that $a+b\mod n,ab\mod n$ turn the set $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ into a ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, which can be now introduced without having to talk about ideals, quotients etc. beforehand.

Comment: Alright I see the problem now. Our maths teachers are of course very "nice" and always write on the table instead of using digital files. And if you haven't been there that's what you get, nothing. Well I guess that's very bad for me..

Comment: All in all, what I did above is correct or not? Or not possible to say because lack of description of the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that:

$$\begin{cases}
a \mod n = r_a\\
b \mod n = r_b\\
(a \cdot b) \mod n = r\\
\end{cases}$$
or equivalently
$$\begin{cases}
a = q_a \cdot n + r_a\\
b = q_b \cdot n + r_b\\
a \cdot b = q \cdot n + r\\
\end{cases}.$$

Then:

$$r_a \cdot r_b = (a-q_a \cdot n)\cdot (b-q_b \cdot n) = \\
= a \cdot b - a \cdot q_b \cdot n - b \cdot q_a \cdot n + q_a \cdot q_b \cdot n^2 = \\
= q \cdot n + r - a \cdot q_b \cdot n - b \cdot q_a \cdot n + q_a \cdot q_b \cdot n^2 = \\
= (q + q_a \cdot q_b \cdot n - a \cdot q_b - b \cdot q_a) \cdot n + r.$$

In other words:

$$r_a \cdot r_b = k \cdot n + r \Rightarrow \\
(r_a \cdot r_b) \mod n =  r \Rightarrow \\
r = (a \cdot b) \text{ mod } n = ((a \text{ mod } n) \cdot (b \text{ mod
} n)) \text{ mod } n .$$

Comment: Wow thank you this looks like a lot work and I cannot imagine doing all this myself in the exam.. :o Thank you for sharing it, I will try my best to understand it. And thanks everyone else for the comments above, too :-)

Comment: @berndgr I guess you will find easier than what you imagine! Please, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer!

Comment: Just one question; what happened to the $k$ at the end?

Comment: @berndgr $k$ is just an integer. In particular $k = q + q_a \cdot q_b \cdot n - a \cdot q_b - b \cdot q_a$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I mean, where did $k$ go here? $$r_{a} \cdot r_{b}=k \cdot n +r \Rightarrow (r_{a} \cdot r_{b}) \text{ mod } n = r$$

Comment: @berndgr This is the definition of the modulus. $k$ just does not matter here.

Comment: Alright I understand everything then, just this was / is a bit confusing :D
By the way, what if we had $r{a}+r_{b}= n \cdot k$ instead? Asking because there was similar task to this just with addition and this is the final result I have. Can I write this to: $(r_{a}+r_{b}) \text{ mod } n = r$ too? I hope I'm not confusing you now.

Comment: @berndgr $$r_{a} \cdot r_{b}=k \cdot n = k \cdot n + 0 \Rightarrow (r_{a} \cdot r_{b}) \text{ mod } n = 0.$$ Hence, $$r=0,$$ no?